# Deciphering 1808 Alsatian German birth record

Tags: germany, birth-records, german-language, 1800s-decade

Having some trouble getting through this civil birth registration record from Issenhausen, Bas-Rhin, Alsace. I've left blanks for words I can't make out.

> Maire von Issenhausene Gemeinde ____ von Geburt von siebenzehnten tag
> des Monathes 9bre im Jahr eintausent acht hundert und acht Geburtsabt
> von Johann George Hässig Geboren den siebenzehnten 9bre abends um fȕnf
> uhr Sohn von Hans Hässig burger und _____ _____ in Issenhause wonhaft
> und von Barbara Klopfenstein seiner Ehefrau. das geschlect des Kindes
> ist _____ ein Knäblein anbauthend an. Erst anzeig Johannes Urbar
> burger und _____ _____ in Issenhausen wonhaft so zwey und dreissig
> Jahre alt ist Zweiyt anzeig Jacob Klein burger und _____ _____ in
> Issenhausen wohhaft so dreissig Jahre alt ist und haben sich
> unterzeichnet. Johannes Hässig Hans Urbar Jacob Klein

[image: 1808 Alsatian German birth record]

Answer (score 0):

Translation is Bellow, But that was most likely a letter before bre than a 9.

**Mayor of Issenhausene Community 1888 Birth Records:** Johann George Hässig Born on the seventeenth day of _bre at five o'clock in the evening son of Hans Hässig burger ___ ___ in Issenhause and of Barbara Klopfenstein his wife . The child's gender is Male. First, report Johannes Urbar burger and _____ _____ in Issenhausen, who lives in Issenhausen, who is about 23 years old, and who has signed. Johannes Hässig Hans Urbar Jacob Klein.

Answer (score 0):

9bre is the standard French abbreviation for November (7bre = September, 8bre = October, 9bre = November, Xbre = December).

Hans Hässig is a "Hirt" (= shepherd).

Johannes Urbar is an "Ackermann" (= farmer) and he's 32, not 23.

The second witness is Jakob Klein, burger and "Ackers", 30 years old. I've never seen the form "Ackers", but it's possibly a variation on "Ackermann".